# PHP - Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make this work. I'm simply trying to fill the `<option>` with the data of the DB from the query.

The error (Trying to get property of non-object in) is on the line of: `if ($result3 -> num_rows > 0) {`

Here is my code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "boleta";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
$rut = "<p id='demo'></p>";
$sql3 = "SELECT numero FROM boleta WHERE pago=0 AND persona_rut =". $rut;
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

        if ($result3 -> num_rows > 0) {
             //output data of each row
             while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=". $row3["numero"]. ">" .$row3["numero"]. "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option>N/A</option>";
        }`
```

Comment: too many unknowns, as to what your DB connection is, and whether you're in fact using `mysqli_` to connect with, DB schema etc. what's being passed for your `$rut` variable. This `WHERE pago=0` could also be a factor.

Comment: Add `or die($conn->error)` to the end of the `query` line to see the MySQL error message.

Comment: I see `$dbname = "boleta";` and `FROM boleta` are both your database and table both the same name? If not, then that's a problem. Plus, where is `$rut` being defined? It's not mentioned in your posted code/question.

Comment: wondering if we need to post an answer to get a response @Barmar

Comment: your query makes no sense `$rut = "<p id='demo'></p>";` and `AND persona_rut =". $rut;` no wonder it's failing. *Moving on....* good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the statement before this is not correct, where you declare $result3.  If your query is coming back with an error, that would cause the PHP error you're getting.  Check for an error on that query and it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: the query works.. I write: echo $sql3; and its give me what it should say to put it in SQL

Comment: @Jcole Add a `var_dump($result3)` right before the offending line and see what you get. If it is "false", you HAVE an error in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If `rut` is a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` column, you need to put the value in quotes:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT numero FROM boleta WHERE pago=0 AND persona_rut ='$rut'";
```

But it would be better to use a prepared statement:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT numero FROM boleta WHERE pago=0 AND persona_rut = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql3);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $rut);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```